# Gessel-Viennot theorem

Tags: symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics

In the [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00001276), page 76, why we need the condition that the subpath lying between lines y=-x and y=k+1 consists entirely of vertical steps?

Comment: It is preferred that MO questions are self-contained, without requiring people to look up a specific page in a paper.